# I got this error in my code. How should I clear this?

Tags: c#, sql, database, error-handling, serenity

This is my code:

```
public MyResponse InsertTeam(MyRow Row) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        var connection = SqlConnections.NewByKey("Cred"); 

        /* Getting Insert to LogBook table */
        TeamRow team = new TeamRow();
        team.TeamId = TeamRow.Fields.TeamId;
        
        var teamId = User.GetIdentifier();
        
        team.CreatedBy = User.GetIdentifier();
        team.CreatedOn = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
    }
    catch 
    { }

    return new SaveResponse();
}
```

I get this error when running it:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Serenity.Data.Int32Field' to 'int?'.

on this line:

```
team.TeamId = TeamRow.Fields.TeamId;
```

How should I clear this?

Comment: I think, but did not test, that this should work: `team.TeamId = TeamRow.Fields.TeamId.getValue`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are directly trying to assign the "Serenity.Data.Int32Field" to a nullable (int?) integer....
if you want so you can explicitly convert the "TeamRow.Fields.TeamId" part to a nullable int? using the value.

```
team.TeamId = (TeamRow.Fields.TeamId == null)
              ? null 
              : TeamRow.Fields.TeamId.Value;
```

or you should check the docs for the Serenity framework, if they provide any explicit method to do so.

Comment: Why you think that there is `Value` property ?

Comment: the .Value is the underlying value of the nullable type, it's the backing field

Comment: Lol, did you read the question? Error states that  `team.TeamId` is nullable, not `TeamRow.Fields.TeamId`